# How to redirect with match params in React Router v6?

Tags: react-router

I used to do this in react router v5:

```
<Redirect exact from="/:org" to="/:org/users" />
```

translating it into this doesn't work:

```
<Route path="/:org" element={<Navigate replace to="/:org/users" />} />
```

What is the correct way to perform this kind of a redirect?

UPD: To clarify – I don't have a separate route for `/:org/users` at the same routes level but I have `/:org/*` route that handles `/:org/users` and others:

```
<Route path="/:org/*" element={<OrgPagesComponent />} />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use relative navigation for the redirect.

```
<Route path="/:org/*" element={<OrgPagesComponent />} />
<Route path="/:org" element={<Navigate to="users" replace />} />
```

When the path matches exactly `"/:org"` the second `Route` will be matched and render the `Navigate` which will ***relatively*** navigate to `"/:org/users"` which is matched by the first `Route` on path `"/:org/*"`.

Here is a running codesandbox demo.

[image: Edit how-to-redirect-with-match-params-in-react-router-v6]

Comment: or  navigate("/users") ,which is the preferred method  from official website.

Comment: @AlbenisKërqeli `navigate` is a function, versus `Navigate` a component. Neither is the "preferred" method as each serves an entirely different purpose/use case. `navigate("/users")` also uses an absolute path and wouldn't work for OP.

Comment: I don't have "users" route, but I have ":org/*" route

Comment: @chingis Sorry, can you specify who you are directing that comment to?

Comment: @DrewReese it was a comment to your answer

Comment: @chingis You are redirecting to a `"/:org/users"` path so I assumed you were rendering a route that could match it. `"/:org/*"` would match `"/:org/users"` that you are wanting to redirect to. Just in case you missed seeing the codesandbox I linked, or you misunderstood it, I've just updated it to render a `"/:org/*"` route instead of a `"/:org/users"` path.

Comment: @DrewReese wow, you're right, that works, I thought you have to have "users" route defined to perform such redirect. Thank you, that's a much better solution than mine

Answer (score 4):

so far I've come up with the following solution:

```
const OrgRedirect = () => {
  const { org } = useParams();
  return <Navigate to={`/${org}/users`} />
}

<Route path="/:org" element={<OrgRedirect />} />
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this helper Component to pass params to Navigate:

```js
function NavigateWithParams({ to, ...rest }) {
  const params = useParams();
  let toValue;
  if (typeof to === 'function') {
    toValue = to(params);
  } else {
    toValue = to;
  }
  return <Navigate to={toValue} {...rest} />
}
```

Usage:

```js
<Route
  path="/test/:id/results"
  element={<NavigateWithParams 
    to={params => `/test/${params.id}/report`} 
    replace
  />}
/>
```